# Ошибка установки Imagick в xampp на macOS

Tags: php, macos, xampp

Пробовал используя homebrew:

`$ brew install imagemagick`

Сейчас пакет якобы установлен:

`Warning: imagemagick-6.9.2-10 already installed`

Используя pecl

`pecl install imagick`

появляется ошибка такого вида:

`Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick`

Полный листинг здесь:

```html
$ sudo -s pecl install imagick
Password:
downloading imagick-3.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.3.0.tgz (179,978 bytes)
......................................done: 179,978 bytes
17 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-imagick
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 6.9.2 Q16
checking for MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header... /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h
checking PHP version is at least 5.1.3... yes. found 5.5.30
checking for ld used by cc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin15.2.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_file.c -o imagick_file.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_file.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_file.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_file.c:85:46: warning: passing 'const char **' to parameter of type 'char **' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
        if (php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(filename, &path_for_open, STREAM_LOCATE_WRAPPERS_ONLY TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/php/main/php_streams.h:552:83: note: passing argument to parameter 'path_for_open' here
PHPAPI php_stream_wrapper *php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(const char *path, char **path_for_open, int options TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                  ^
1 warning generated.
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c -o imagick_class.lo
 cc -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_class.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:295:10: warning: 'MagickGetImageMatte' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        matte = MagickGetImageMatte(intern->magick_wand);
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:82:3: note: 'MagickGetImageMatte' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickGetImageMatte(MagickWand *) magick_attribute((deprecated)),
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:1204:12: warning: 'MagickPaintFloodfillImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                status = MagickPaintFloodfillImage(intern->magick_wand, channel, fill_wand, fuzz, NULL, x, y);
                         ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:99:3: note: 'MagickPaintFloodfillImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickPaintFloodfillImage(MagickWand *,const ChannelType,const PixelWand *,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:1212:12: warning: 'MagickPaintFloodfillImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                status = MagickPaintFloodfillImage(intern->magick_wand, channel, fill_wand, fuzz, border_wand, x, y);
                         ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:99:3: note: 'MagickPaintFloodfillImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickPaintFloodfillImage(MagickWand *,const ChannelType,const PixelWand *,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:1673:11: warning: 'MagickRecolorImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickRecolorImage(intern->magick_wand, order, array);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:113:3: note: 'MagickRecolorImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickRecolorImage(MagickWand *,const size_t,const double *)
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:3951:11: warning: 'MagickColorFloodfillImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickColorFloodfillImage(intern->magick_wand, fill_wand, fuzz, border_wand, x, y);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:75:3: note: 'MagickColorFloodfillImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickColorFloodfillImage(MagickWand *,const PixelWand *,const double,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:4369:11: warning: 'MagickMapImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickMapImage(intern->magick_wand, intern_map->magick_wand, dither);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:86:3: note: 'MagickMapImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickMapImage(MagickWand *,const MagickWand *,const MagickBooleanType)
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:4408:11: warning: 'MagickMatteFloodfillImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickMatteFloodfillImage(intern->magick_wand, alpha, fuzz, color_wand, x, y);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:88:3: note: 'MagickMatteFloodfillImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickMatteFloodfillImage(MagickWand *,const double,const double,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:4444:11: warning: 'MagickMedianFilterImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickMedianFilterImage(intern->magick_wand, radius);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/magick-image.h:222:3: note: 'MagickMedianFilterImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickMedianFilterImage(MagickWand *,const double),
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:4524:11: warning: 'MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel(intern->magick_wand, channel, target_wand, fill_wand, fuzz);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:104:3: note: 'MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickPaintOpaqueImageChannel(MagickWand *,const ChannelType,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:4605:11: warning: 'MagickPaintTransparentImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickPaintTransparentImage(intern->magick_wand, color_wand, alpha, fuzz);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:107:3: note: 'MagickPaintTransparentImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickPaintTransparentImage(MagickWand *,const PixelWand *,const double,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:4767:11: warning: 'MagickReduceNoiseImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickReduceNoiseImage(intern->magick_wand, radius);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/magick-image.h:269:3: note: 'MagickReduceNoiseImage' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickReduceNoiseImage(MagickWand *,const double),
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:5935:14: warning: 'MagickGetImageAttribute' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        attribute = MagickGetImageAttribute(intern->magick_wand, key);
                    ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:59:4: note: 'MagickGetImageAttribute' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  *MagickGetImageAttribute(MagickWand *,const char *)
   ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:6139:11: warning: 'MagickGetImageChannelExtrema' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickGetImageChannelExtrema(intern->magick_wand, channel_type, &minima, &maxima);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:78:3: note: 'MagickGetImageChannelExtrema' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickGetImageChannelExtrema(MagickWand *,const ChannelType,size_t *,
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:6413:11: warning: 'MagickGetImageExtrema' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickGetImageExtrema(intern->magick_wand, &min, &max);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:80:3: note: 'MagickGetImageExtrema' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickGetImageExtrema(MagickWand *,size_t *,size_t *)
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:7383:11: warning: 'MagickGetImageIndex' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickGetImageIndex(intern->magick_wand);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:65:3: note: 'MagickGetImageIndex' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickGetImageIndex(MagickWand *) magick_attribute((deprecated));
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:7408:11: warning: 'MagickSetImageIndex' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickSetImageIndex(intern->magick_wand, index);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:117:3: note: 'MagickSetImageIndex' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickSetImageIndex(MagickWand *,const ssize_t)
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:7493:32: warning: 'MagickGetImageSize' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        ZVAL_LONG(return_value, (long)MagickGetImageSize(intern->magick_wand));
                                      ^
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:564:19: note: expanded from macro 'ZVAL_LONG'
                Z_LVAL_P(__z) = l;                      \
                                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:144:3: note: 'MagickGetImageSize' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickGetImageSize(MagickWand *) magick_attribute((deprecated));
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:7910:11: warning: 'MagickSetImageAttribute' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickSetImageAttribute(intern->magick_wand, key, attribute);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:115:3: note: 'MagickSetImageAttribute' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickSetImageAttribute(MagickWand *,const char *,const char *)
  ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:8225:13: warning: 'MagickFlattenImages' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        tmp_wand = MagickFlattenImages(intern->magick_wand);
                   ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:136:4: note: 'MagickFlattenImages' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  *MagickFlattenImages(MagickWand *) magick_attribute((deprecated)),
   ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:9381:13: warning: 'MagickAverageImages' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        tmp_wand = MagickAverageImages(intern->magick_wand);
                   ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:135:4: note: 'MagickAverageImages' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  *MagickAverageImages(MagickWand *) magick_attribute((deprecated)),
   ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:9873:13: warning: 'MagickMosaicImages' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        tmp_wand = MagickMosaicImages(intern->magick_wand);
                   ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:139:4: note: 'MagickMosaicImages' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  *MagickMosaicImages(MagickWand *) magick_attribute((deprecated)),
   ^
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagick_class.c:10002:11: warning: 'MagickRadialBlurImageChannel' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        status = MagickRadialBlurImageChannel(intern->magick_wand, channel, angle);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/deprecate.h:111:3: note: 'MagickRadialBlurImageChannel' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  MagickRadialBlurImageChannel(MagickWand *,const ChannelType,const double)
  ^
22 warnings generated.
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6 -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/include/ImageMagick-6  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/imagickdraw_class.c -o imagickdraw_class.lo
L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/lib -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
cc ${wl}-flat_namespace ${wl}-undefined ${wl}suppress -o .libs/imagick.so -bundle  .libs/imagick_file.o .libs/imagick_class.o .libs/imagickdraw_class.o .libs/imagickpixel_class.o .libs/imagickpixeliterator_class.o .libs/imagick_helpers.o .libs/imagick.o .libs/imagickkernel_class.o  -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/lib /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2/lib /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.dylib  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-10/lib
dsymutil .libs/imagick.so || :
creating imagick.la
(cd .libs && rm -f imagick.la && ln -s ../imagick.la imagick.la)
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/libtool --mode=install cp ./imagick.la /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/modules
cp ./.libs/imagick.so /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/modules/imagick.so
cp ./.libs/imagick.lai /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/modules/imagick.la
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/imagick-3.3.0/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0" install
Installing shared extensions:     /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
Installing header files:          /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/include/php/
running: find "/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0" | xargs ls -dils
6103196   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0
6103574   0 drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel     136  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr
6103582   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/include
6103583   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/include/php
6103584   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/include/php/ext
6103585   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/include/php/ext/imagick
6103586   8 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    1828  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h
6103575   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/lib
6103576   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/lib/php
6103577   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/lib/php/extensions
6103578   0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
6103579 824 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  420872  5 янв 21:19 /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootOxkhao/install-imagick-3.3.0/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: `brew install php5-imagick`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Библиотека получается устанавливается так `brew install imagemagick `. В консоле появляется сообщение `Warning: imagemagick-6.9.2-10 already installed`. При вводе `brew install php5-imagick` выводится `Error: No available formula with the name "php5-imagick" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`. Делал как пишет автор ответа http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196210/install-imagemagick-for-xampp-on-mac

Comment: судя по `ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick` он не может перейти к указанной директории. Просто там нет этой папки. И сам ее почему-то тоже не создает?

Comment: На макоси не работал но в кратце система такая ест библиотека `imagemagick` и обертка для php ( `php5-imagick` ) . Так вот нужна сначала устанавливать `imagemagick` а потом `php5-imagick`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865600/imagemagick-brew-installation-with-php-module-in-mac-os-x. Если в кратце если `php5-imagick` нет поищи `brew search imagick`

Comment: Ты как su запускаеш?

Comment: @E_p Спасибо! Используя brew search imagick нашел нужный пакет! Нужно было  полностью версию прописать. В моем случае это `brew install homebrew/php/php55-imagick`. После этого `pecl install imagick` прошел без ошибок. Сказал прописать в php.ini `extension=imagick.so`. В моем случае исходя из phpinfo() - используется директория "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini", также после установки есть  и в "/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/php.ini" - прописал и там, и там. Пока не работает.

Comment: Restart apache ;)

Comment: Уже много раз restart делал. Прописал полный путь в php.ini - "[imagick] 
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-imagick/3.3.0/imagick.so"  - не хотиИТ собака))

Comment: Проверь права доступа на файл. И лог ошибок апача и ПХП.

Comment: Еще по идее после установки php55-imagick pecl не нужно. Кстати какую версию пхп xampp  гоняет?

Comment: Почитал, походу много гемора imagick под XAMPP  устанавливать не проще VM с Ubuntu запустить? :)

Comment: У меня версия php 5.5.24. Завтра снесу все и установлю по новой. Видать, что-то неправильно сделал раз не работает.

Comment: https://guynathan.com/install-lamp-stack-on-mavericks-with-homebrew-with-php-mcrypt without XAMPP

Comment: Не хотел запариваться с vm. Так можно было бы и винду накатить с OpenServer, где Imagick уже вшит в пакет.

Comment: Не для сервера винда не подойдет :).

Comment: Мне для разработки нужно. xampp на mac работает нормально, только вот с imagickoм чет проблема возникла.

Comment: Спасиб тебе за ответы, помогли по крайней мере в корректной установке!

Comment: @E_p Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: Проблема была в несовместимости версий библиотек. В PHP логе присутствовала ошибка `Reason: Incompatible library version: libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib requires version 19.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 15.0.0 in Unknown on line 0`. Скопировал  файлы из `/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib` в  директорию `/Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/lib/`. Решение взято отсюда - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300822/xampp-cant-load-imagick-incompatible-library-versions#comment35714216_23300822  . Всё заработало!!!